# Doing a Pull Request to latest commit on server

Tags: git, version-control

Let' assume the last commits in my server are like this:

```
A1 -> A2 -> A3
```

My local repo is synced with server, and now I branch from A3:

```
A3  
|  
B1 -> B2 -> B3
```

Finally I have finished my task in commit B3 and I want to push to server and merge (PR). But in server someone else added new commits:

```
A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> A4 -> A5
```

Reviewing A4 and A5, I see there is no conflict with my work on B3, so I want to merge my work as if I branched directly from A5. It looks a really common task, what the correct way to do it?

Comment: Is A4 and A5 also pushed to the remote like A1-A3? Where are you wanting to merge B into? Are you wanting to merge it back into A?

Comment: @DrZoo, Yes. Just imagine I got code from server, finished and when I want merge back, there is new work there. The ideal is merge back to A3 (from I originally branched) but there are new commits there (A4 and A5) and now I prefer merge directly to A5.

Comment: You're creating some confusion when you use the word commit. You seem to be using it interchangeably. A `git commit` is when your local repo has the changes. `git push` is when the local changes, are pushed to the remote so anyone can pull them in. Are these A4-A5 commits only on someones local, or the remote? [Git diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgaV9.png)

Comment: @DrZoo In remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how you do your pull requests. If A1-A5 and B1-B3 are all pushed to the remote on each branch, all you have to do is hop onto branch A or B and then `git pull remote origin BRANCH A/B` name. Since you were working on B, just do `git pull remote origin BRANCH A` while on branch B. This will then give you A1-A5 and B1-B3 on the same branch. Then use branch B to create a PR to master.

Alternatively (the right way in my opinion) is to make a PR for A to master and a PR for B to master. The overlap of A that is already in B shouldn't cause any problems.

If A and B were not related at all, you should have branched B off of your develop, or equivalent branch.

Here's an example of a [non-linear branching strategy](https://nvie.com/img/git-model@2x.png) for more complex work flows.

Seeing this [linear vs. non-linear workflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=linear+branching+strategy&sxsrf=ACYBGNRb-u1fASp36fnjsVmQmLLKFkJOHg:1569275325537&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRkdWS9ufkAhVMqJ4KHU1NAqAQ_AUIEigB&biw=1920&bih=1057#imgrc=D__XeFNILqSkaM:) may help better visualize the mess that is going on.

If my explanation and understanding of your scenario is incorrect, let me know so I can change or completely remove the answer.